# iOS In App purchase when buying something can I send some extra thing with the product identifier？

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am implementing the In-App Purchase in iOS and the server want me to: "when buying something, I send some extra arguments such as user id, game zone id, and our unique order id with the product identifier, after the purchase success, Apple server send these value back". Can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can send all the details you want just after receiving success message of In App purchase. For unique order Id you can just use UUID of the device.

Comment: Using the UUID is now deprecated. Use identifierForVendor instead

Comment: I just wonder How can I  send these values to apple server ? Can you show me some code ?

Comment: Why you want to provide these values to apple server, they won't be accepting your custom values, you can try above answer for your server only.